# Is it possible to shift a geopandas world map on the x axis (longitude)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I'm wondering if there is a way to center a geopandas world map on a particular point of longitude. Basically, just wanting to shift it by about ~5-10 degrees or so.

A previous question was posted several months ago, but didn't receive an answer. Wondering if anyone knows the solution. (Link to the original question on stackoverflow is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750837/set-centre-of-geopandas-map))

```
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
world.plot(ax=ax, color=(0.8,0.5,0.5))
```

Would really appreciate it if someone could help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need the whole shifted world? Or is it enough, that it is just shifted?

Comment: I would need the whole world shifted (if possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out how to do it:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.ops import split
from shapely.affinity import translate
import geopandas

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

def shift_map(shift):
    shift -= 180
    moved_map = []
    splitted_map = []
    border = LineString([(shift,90),(shift,-90)])
    for row in world["geometry"]:
        splitted_map.append(split(row, border))
    for element in splitted_map:
        items = list(element)
        for item in items:
            minx, miny, maxx, maxy = item.bounds
            if minx >= shift:
                moved_map.append(translate(item, xoff=-180-shift))
            else:
                moved_map.append(translate(item, xoff=180-shift))
    gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({"geometry":moved_map})
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    gdf.plot(ax=ax)
    plt.show()
```

In the first step, you create your world and split it on a pre defined border of yours.
Then you get the bounds of all elements and check if the bounds match your desired shift. Afterwards you translate every element bigger than your border to the left side of the map and move all other elements to the right side, so that they aling with +180°.

This gives you for example:
[image: Shifted map by 120°]

A map shifted by 120°

Comment: Btw, forgot to say thanks! That's a fantastic answer and provides the exact detail I needed!

Comment: No problem! Glad, I could help :D

Comment: Longitude labelling is not shifted accordingly, zero longitude is still in the middle.

Comment: Is this still the best answer? It's fine, but it just feels a bit ridiculous to have to do this for what seems like a basic geographic transformation, and also it's just one special case. Is there nothing built in? In general I'd want to be able to easily centre maps on any location on the sphere, with any rotation angles, in any map projection. Maybe that's the general solution, to define a custom projection/co-ordinate system and reproject to that?