# geopandas map centering with countries

Tags: matplotlib, geospatial, geopandas

I am plotting data for ex-ussr on geopandas and it really does not look nice.

[image: awkward img]

I tried this code published early on [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64004110/is-it-possible-to-shift-a-geopandas-world-map-on-the-x-axis-longitude), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65096171/geopandas-map-centering-the-country-on-the-plot-and-joining-its-split-geometri), but adds no help hence I don't need just map, I need to put data on it. And because I'm merging the 'world' (actually consisting only of ex-ussr countries) and coronavirus data "on 'Country'", then I need that dataframe with original country and adjusted polygone.

Key peaces of my code:

```
url = "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/a21fdb46d23e4ef896f31475217cbb08_1.geojson"
world = gpd.read_file(url)
ex_ussr = ['Ukraine', 'Belarus', 'Kyrgyzstan', 'Azerbaijan', 'Tajikistan', 'Armenia', 'Georgia', 'Russia', 'Kazakhstan', 'Lithuania', 'Latvia', 'Estonia', 'Uzbekistan']
world = world[world['CNTRY_NAME'].isin(ex_ussr)]
df_world = pd.merge(df_covid, world, on='Country')
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
corona_gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_world, crs=crs, geometry='geometry')
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(30,5))
ax = corona_gpd.plot(column='New cases', cmap='rainbow', ax=ax, legend=True, legend_kwds={'label': 'New Cases by Country'})
```

Comment: Have you tried a different projection? you might need to use cartopy

Comment: I tried to shift map, but I can't plot on shifted map...
I early found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEoDhO_Zuyc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a challenging question that I am happy to try. The following is a runnable code that will create a geodataframe of `russia` with good geometry -- the geometry that does not spread apart at the dateline.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

#import cartopy.crs as ccrs
#import cartopy

from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiPolygon, Polygon
from shapely.ops import split
from shapely.affinity import translate
import geopandas

def shift_geom(shift, gdataframe, plotQ=False):
    # this code is adapted from somewhere found in SO
    # *** will give credit here ***
    shift -= 180
    moved_map = []
    splitted_map = []
    border = LineString([(shift,90),(shift,-90)])

    for row in gdataframe["geometry"]:
        splitted_map.append(split(row, border))
    for element in splitted_map:
        items = list(element)
        for item in items:
            minx, miny, maxx, maxy = item.bounds
            if minx >= shift:
                moved_map.append(translate(item, xoff=-180-shift))
            else:
                moved_map.append(translate(item, xoff=180-shift))

    # got `moved_map` as the moved geometry            
    gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({"geometry": moved_map})
    # can move back to original pos by rerun with -ve shift

    # can change crs here
    if plotQ:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        gdf.plot(ax=ax)
        plt.show()

    return gdf


world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = world[['name', 'continent', 'geometry', 'pop_est', 'gdp_md_est']]

ex_ussr = ['Ukraine', 'Belarus', 'Kyrgyzstan', 'Azerbaijan', 'Tajikistan', 'Armenia', \
           'Georgia', 'Kazakhstan', 'Lithuania', 'Latvia', 'Estonia', 'Uzbekistan']

# ex_ussr w/o russia
ex_ussr_gdf = world[world['name'].isin(ex_ussr)]
# russia only
russia = world[ world['name']=='Russia' ]

# manipulate russia's geometry
rus_shift_90 = shift_geom(90, russia, False)        # Do not plot
good_geom_rus = shift_geom(-90, rus_shift_90, True) # Plot it

# a plot of new geometry appears
```

[image: good-russ]

```
# Create geodataframe with 1 row (Multi-polygon) using this geometry
newrus_gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame( { "name": ["Russia"] , "new_geometry": [good_geom_rus.geometry.unary_union]}, \
                             geometry="new_geometry", crs="EPSG:4326")
# Merge `russia` with `newrus_gdf` to get everything in 1 dataframe
russia_final = russia.merge(right=newrus_gdf , on="name")

# Set the `new_geometry` from `newrus_gdf` as the geometry
russia_final.set_geometry("new_geometry", drop=True, inplace=True)

# plot all ex_ussr together = `russia_final` + `ex_ussr_gdf`
rus_ax = russia_final.plot(color='brown')
ex_ussr_gdf.plot(ax=rus_ax, color="green", ec="black", lw=0.3, alpha=0.75)
```

[image: final_exussr]

**Edit**

To add `russia_final` to `ex_ussr_gdf` and plot the result, run this code:-

```
ex_ussr_gdf = ex_ussr_gdf.append(russia_final, ignore_index=True)
ex_ussr_gdf.plot(color="pink", ec="black", lw=0.3)
```

[image: new_exussr]

Comment: I tried the same logic to create the ex_ussr with "Russia" in a gdf with shifted geometry, but got error.
I need new gdf for the ex_ussr with "Russia" because then I merge it with "covid" dataframe with 2 columns - "Country", "Total cases". Then I plot a rainbow map on covid data with this: 
```
df_exussr = pd.merge(covid_data, ex_ussr_gdf, on='Country')
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
corona_gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_exussr, crs=crs, geometry='geometry')
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(30,5))
ax = corona_gpd.plot(column='Total cases', cmap='rainbow', ax=ax, legend=True)
```

Comment: I tried appending merging covid data with russian and ex_ussr gdf separately. Then appended ex_ussr to russian gdf. I'm trying to plot rainbow map but instead getting error "'Line2D' object has no property 'column'"

Comment: @H.Turdiev Please check my edited answer. Remember one question should focus on single topic. Related questions can be asked as new questions, so that, other people can see and help more effectively.

Comment: it worked! And more important, I understood why :D thank you! you're genius!

Comment: @H.Turdiev Then, consider accepting my answer by clicking the `accept` button. You will get some points as a good questioner.

Comment: I'm sorry Mr. swatchai
I'm completely newby in stackoverflow

Comment: @H.Turdiev Your question is good and useful, 1 upvote.