# Drawing Worldmap Whose Center Is Japan With Geopandas

Tags: python-3.x, windows, geopandas

**Before reading my question, my english skill is poor, so please send me feedback or advise in easy words. Thank you.**

## What I wand to do:

I want to draw an worldmap whose center is Japan with geopandas library on python 3.x.

## My Environment:

- Windows10 (64bit)
- Python v3.9.4
- geopandas v0.9.0

## My Code:

```
import geopandas

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
world.boundary.plot(figsize=(15,8))
```

## The Obtained Image

[world image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7DO6.png)

## Question:

The center of an obtained worldmap drawing is arouond Africa. I want to draw the image whose center is Japan. I read an official document: [Mapping and Plotting Tools](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/mapping.html), but I can not find how to realize it. Please tell me advices !!

Comment: have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009989/13168978)

Answer (score 1):

I found working with `geopandas` (+ `pyproj` as its dependency) to get the shifted map is too difficult. In my code below, `geopandas` is used to provide the geodataframe of the world to manipulate and plot. `Cartopy` is used to provide the `geoaxis` for proper geospatial referencing. And `shapely` is used to do all sorts of manipulation to transform geometries for plotting re-centered world plot to meet the requirements in the question.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiPolygon, Polygon
from shapely.ops import split
from shapely.affinity import translate

from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import geopandas

def shift_map(world_gdf, shift, ax):
    # world_gdf: world geodataframe to shift
    # shift: longitude shift
    # ax: geoaxis to plot the map
    shift -= 180
    moved_map = []
    splitted_map = []
    border = LineString([(shift,90),(shift,-90)])
    for row in world_gdf["geometry"]:
        splitted_map.append(split(row, border))
    for element in splitted_map:
        items = list(element)
        for item in items:
            minx, miny, maxx, maxy = item.bounds
            if minx >= shift:
                moved_map.append(translate(item, xoff=-180-shift))
            else:
                moved_map.append(translate(item, xoff=180-shift))

    gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({"geometry": moved_map})
    gdf.boundary.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1, color='gray')
    # can also use: gdf.plot() to plot the geometries as polygons


# define CRS's 
crs0 = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0)         # standard CRS
lon_0 = 138                                          # Japan at center
# crsJapan = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=lon_0) # japan's centered; not in-use
# a special CRS for use with ax1.gridlines() to get correct longitude's labels plot
crsGridLines = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=-lon_0)

# create figure, axis
# use cartopy ccrs to get some niceties
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4.5), subplot_kw={"projection": crs0})

# load world geodataframe
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

# Plot the shifted map
shift_map(world, lon_0, ax1)

# Plot graticule/grid; only work with geoaxis
gl = ax1.gridlines(crs=crsGridLines, draw_labels=True, linewidth=1, color='gray', linestyle='--')
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 10, 'color': 'black'}
gl.ylabel_style = {'size': 10, 'color': 'black'}

plt.show()
```

[image: japan-centered-map]