# Is it possible to center a map using geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas

I am plotting pairs of points over a geopandas map. Everything works but the problem is that the default world map plot centers in the Atlantic Ocean, but I would like it to center in the Pacific Ocean. I've looked through the documentation and I can't find a way to do it.

Picture of how the map plots by default:

[image]

Picture of how I would like the map to plot:

[image]

The plot can be reproduced using the following code:

```
import geopandas
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.plot()
```

I have tried using: `plt.xlim([180,-180])`

This flips the map, but doesn't shift the center.

I have tried: `plt.xlim([0,360])`

but as expected, this does not work because matplotlib does not know that longitudes can be also set from 0 to 360.

Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750837/set-centre-of-geopandas-map) to be very helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set centre of geopandas map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750837/set-centre-of-geopandas-map)

Comment: oh yes, I think these are what I am looking forward. Thank you. I'll give these a try.

Comment: simply shifting the map definitely works and seems to be what you're asking for. but I'd also encourage you to check out the geopandas docs on [plotting in geopandas with cartopy](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/cartopy_convert.html), which allows you to use different map projections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who responded. I adapted Russell Jarvis' solution from [Set centre of geopandas map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750837/set-centre-of-geopandas-map). I am sharing because the previous answer was using networkx and I used geopandas DataFrame and updated the geometry directly, returning the updated dataframe. I apologize for overlooking these, it seems that when I created the question, I typed "contextily" instead of "geopandas" and missed them!

```
def shift_geom(self,shift, gdataframe, gdf1, gdf2, plotQ=True):
    # this code is adapted from answer found in SO
    # will be credited here: ???
    shift -= 180
    moved_geom = []
    splitted_geom = []
    border = LineString([(shift,90),(shift,-90)])

    for row in gdataframe["geometry"]:
        splitted_geom.append(split(row, border))
    for element in splitted_geom:
        items = list(element)
        for item in items:
            minx, miny, maxx, maxy = item.bounds
            if minx >= shift:
                moved_geom.append(translate(item, xoff=-180-shift))
            else:
                moved_geom.append(translate(item, xoff=180-shift))

    # got `moved_geom` as the moved geometry            
    moved_geom_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"geometry": moved_geom})

    # can change crs here
    if plotQ:
        fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=[8,6])
        moved_geom_gdf.plot(ax=ax1)
        plt.show()
        
    geom1 = gdf1.geometry.values
    geom2 = gdf2.geometry.values
    moved_map_points1 = []
    moved_map_points2 = []
    lines = []


    for element in geom1:

        if float(element.x) >= shift:        
            moved_map_points1.append(translate(element, xoff=-180-shift))
        else:
            moved_map_points1.append(translate(element, xoff=180-shift))

    for element in geom2:

        if float(element.x) >= shift:        
            moved_map_points2.append(translate(element, xoff=-180-shift))
        else:
            moved_map_points2.append(translate(element, xoff=180-shift))
        
    gdf1 = gdf1.set_geometry(moved_map_points1)
    gdf2 = gdf2.set_geometry(moved_map_points2)
    
    for el in range(len(moved_map_points1)):
        lines.append(LineString([(moved_map_points1[el].x, moved_map_points1[el].y),
(moved_map_points2[el].x, moved_map_points2[el].y)]))
    
    gdfl = gdfl.set_geometry(lines)

    return moved_geom_gdf,gdf1,gdf2,gdfl
```

This results in the following map:
[image: shifted geopandas map with points linked with line]

Comment: If you want to label longitude correctly? Just ask it as a new question.